# Barefoot World-trip

Tags: legal, culture, cultural-awareness

I am an avid barefoot walker. In fact did not wear any shoes since 2 years.  Did already barefoot travel in parts the western world without any mayor problem. Although in some countries I got more diverse reactions then in others, It was a very positive experience.

Now I have the time and money to travel the world in a round trip. And I am not planning to wear any shoes.
Apart from the obvious physical limitations, i.e. Siberia in winter, broken glass and some tropical diseases, I am more concerned about very negative reactions of other humans. So...

**In which non-western countries would I run into serious cultural or even legal problems with barefoot travelling ?**

**Or on the other hand, where would barefoot travel not even raise an eyebrow?**

Comment: Related: [Banana hammock on a domestic US flight? (closed)](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/76944/32134)